# What command could be used obtain system hardware specs on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I will like to see my hardware specs in my ubuntu desktop.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [HardInfo](http://hardinfo.berlios.de/HomePage)

[image]
<sub>(source: [hardinfo.org](http://wiki.hardinfo.org/images/shots/Summary.png))</sub>

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hardinfo && hardinfo

[Ubuntu forum Discussion Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=801248)

Answer (score 5):

`dmidecode` is my go-to tool for finding out what hardware's on a machine.  If you're just after basic info, `lspci` touches most of the high notes.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install lshw && sudo lshw
```

Or, if you want a graphical display:

```
sudo apt-get install lshw-gtk && sudo lshw -X
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out [HardwareLiSter](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter). It can provide output on the command line, as HTML, and also has a GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been discussed.  There are some additional answers here:  [How to find out details about hardware on the Linux machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48642/how-to-find-out-details-about-hardware-on-the-linux-machine/)